# Need to see only modified column updates only when name column gets changed/update

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library

I have columns in SharePoint library Name(doc), team, tiers, modified
Here I need modified column change only when name is updated/checkout and modified should not changed when team tiers is edited/updated.

Comment: Are you talking about SharePoint default "Modified" column or you have created custom column for this?

Comment: Sharepoint Online or On Premises?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, SharePoint default "Modified"

Comment: @VictorBuzin SharePoint on premises

Comment: You cannot change behavior of SharePoint default modified column. You may need to create a new date type column for your requirements.

Comment: how to create a new date for this requirement?